# Issue reading dropdown box text

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to check the selected value of a dropdown box if its "Please Select.." I need to show the relevant alert message saying please select, but even if I choose "ETF Too Big" from the drop down box I still get the alert box saying please select. Can someone please correct my error below as I can't see where I have gone wrong. When I hover over the variable `Diarised` it shows me the relevant selected text from the drop down but yet it still gives me the alert box.

```
var Diarised = $('[id*=drpDiarisedReason] :selected').text();
                    if (Diarised == "Please Select..");
                    {
                        alert('Please Select Diarised Reason');
                        return false;
                    }
```

This is my HTML

```
<select id="drpDiarisedReason">
        <option value="">Please Select..</option>
        <option value="1">ETF Too Big</option>
        <option value="2">Equipment Cost</option>
        <option value="3">Spend Too Little</option>
    </select>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: $('#drpDiarisedReason').val() will contain the selected value, you  can check if it's "Please Select..." and handle accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($('#drpDiarisedReason').val()=== "")
{
    alert('Please Select Diarised Reason');
    return false;
}
```

See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/7SFH8/)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
var text = $('#drpDiarisedReason').val();
```

Read more about [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)